# Pausable typewriter effect in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, text

I'm using the typewriter plugin from [Jason Frame's Grab Bag](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/jquery-grab-bag/text-effects.html).

However, I now find myself in a situation where I need to be able to pause and resume this typewriter at any point during its run.

Ideally, I'd have `.typewriter("pause")` to pause it, and `.typewriter("resume")` to resume the animation from where it left off.

I've tried setting a `paused` variable within the plugin, and leaving the interval running with a check for the variable each iteration -- if true, do nothing.

However, due to my lack of skills in making jQuery plug-ins, each time I call the function to pause the typewriter, it just starts all over again. I suspect the `paused` variable gets reset.

How would I go about making this plugin pausable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/eguxev/1/edit)*

Add this 2 lines here:

```
(function($) {      
    $.fn.typewriter = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            var $ele = $(this), str = $ele.text(), progress = 0;
            $ele.text('');
            timer = setInterval(function() {
              if(pause===false){    // ADD THIS LINE ////////////////////////
                  $ele.text(str.substring(0, progress++) + (progress & 1 ? '_' : ''));
                  if (progress >= str.length) clearInterval(timer);
              }                     // ADD THIS LINE ////////////////////////
            }, 100);
        });
        return this;
    };   
})(jQuery);

$("#typewriter").typewriter(); // run your plugin
```

and I created this:

```
var pause = false;
$('#play_pause').click(function(){
  pause= !pause ? true : false;    // toggle true/false pause states
});
```

**EDIT:** find a better *plugin-like* solution in the comment below!

Comment: Well that was surprisingly simplistic -- although, that would pause all running typewriters simultaneously. Is there a solution to contain the pause variable within each instance of the plugin?

Comment: You're welcome be aware that the method I used might not suit well the plugin version for multiple elements.

Comment: @EmphramStavanger but if you'll have a button for each element than you can use this plugin improvement: http://jsbin.com/eguxev/3/edit (change in the plugin the **selector** [I use `.prev()`] that points to the element-previous button)